# KeyError for a Key in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, padding, keyerror

I have a dictionary (cell0) with keys as shown below. It is clear that there is a key with name '46' in my dictionary. And I have confirmed that there is proper data in that key. When I use a for loop and try to iterate over the dictionary to perform some task, It shows me "KeyError : 46" . Can anyone help understand why this is happening?

```
cell0.keys()

dict_keys(['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78', '79', '80', '81', '82', '83', '84', '85', '86', '87', '88', '89', '90', '91', '92', '93', '94', '95', '96', '97', '98', '99', '100', '101', '102', '103', '104', '105', '106', '107', '108', '109', '110', '111', '112', '113', '114', '115', '116', '117', '118', '119', '120', '121', '122', '123', '124', '125', '126', '127', '128', '129', '130', '131', '132', '133', '134', '135', '136', '137', '138', '139', '140', '141', '142', '143', '144', '145', '146', '147', '148', '149', '150', '151', '152', '153', '154', '155', '156', '157', '158', '159', '160', '161', '162', '163', '164', '165', '166', '167', '168', '169', '170', '171', '172', '173', '174', '175', '176', '177', '178', '179', '180', '181', '182', '183', '184', '185', '186', '187', '188', '189', '190', '191', '192', '193', '194', '195', '196', '197', '198', '199', '200', '201', '202', '203', '204', '205', '206', '207', '208', '209', '210', '211', '212', '213', '214', '215', '216', '217', '218', '219', '220', '221', '222', '223', '224', '225', '226', '227', '228', '229', '230', '231', '232', '233', '234', '235', '236', '237', '238', '239', '240', '241', '242', '243', '244', '245', '246', '247', '248', '249', '250', '251', '252', '253', '254', '255', '256', '257', '258', '259', '260', '261', '262', '263', '264', '265', '266', '267', '268', '269', '270', '271', '272', '273', '274', '275', '276', '277', '278', '279', '280', '281', '282', '283', '284', '285', '286', '287', '288', '289', '290', '291', '292', '293', '294', '295', '296', '297', '298', '299', '300', '301', '302', '303', '304', '305', '306', '307', '308', '309', '310', '311', '312', '313', '314', '315', '316', '317', '318', '319', '320', '321', '322', '323', '324', '325', '326', '327', '328', '329', '330', '331', '332', '333', '334', '335', '336', '337', '338', '339', '340', '341', '342', '343', '344', '345', '346', '347', '348', '349', '350', '351', '352', '353', '354', '355', '356', '357', '358', '359', '360', '361', '362', '363', '364', '365', '366', '367', '368', '369', '370', '371', '372', '373', '374', '375', '376', '377', '378', '379', '380', '381', '382', '383', '384', '385', '386', '387', '388', '389', '390', '391', '392', '393', '394', '395', '396', '397', '398', '399', '400', '401', '402', '403', '404', '405', '406', '407', '408', '409', '410', '411', '412', '413', '414', '415', '416', '417', '418', '419', '420', '421', '422', '423', '424', '425', '426', '427', '428', '429', '430', '431', '432', '433', '434', '435', '436', '437', '438', '439', '440', '441', '442', '443', '444', '445', '446', '447', '448', '449', '450', '451', '452', '453', '454', '455', '456', '457', '458', '459', '460', '461', '462', '463', '464', '465', '466', '467', '468', '469', '470', '471', '472', '473', '474', '475', '476', '477', '478', '479', '480', '481', '482', '483', '484', '485', '486', '487', '488', '489', '490', '491', '492', '493', '494', '495'])
```

I performed the following padding operation to make all the arrays into same size.

```
for key in cell0:

for i in cell0[i]:
    x = cell0[i]['I'].shape
    x = sum(x)
    y = cell0[i][key].shape
    y = sum(y)
    l = (x-y)

    if x != y:
        cell0[i][key] = np.pad((cell0[i][key]),[(0,l)],mode='constant', constant_values=0)
```

When I run the cell with the above code, I get an error like this.

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-0955afc863ef> in <module>
  1 for key in cell0:
  2 
  ----> 3     for i in cell0[i]:
  4         x = cell0[i]['I'].shape
  5         x = sum(x)

KeyError: 46
```

Comment: `'46'` and `46` are not equal, they are values of two entirely different types.

Comment: It looks like the difference between the string `'46'` and the integer `46`.

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code correctly?  What you have above is not legal Python.  Your first line is a for loop with no body.  Your next line is a for loop that defines `i` in terms of `i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if cell0 is dictionary you can not slice it
----> for i in cell0[i]

consider that also 'dict_keys'(cell0.keys()) object is not subscriptable

you can use cell0.items() to access both key and value

as a note it is better to use cell0.get(key) method to access value in a dict

```
for key, value in cell0.items():
     x = value.get("I").shape()
     ...# your code
```